# Wxpython: How to bind keyboard events of windows os directly with Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have designed a **file copy software** in python with GUI in **Wxpython**. Now I want to bind Windows standard keyboard event **"CTRL+V"** to my application so that when any user presses "CTRL+V" then my application automaticaly copies that file to it destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Accelerator Table

```
def OnPaste(evt):
    pass #do something

pasteID = wx.NewId()
aTable = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('V'), pasteID ),])
my_main_frame.SetAcceleratorTable(aTable)
my_main_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,OnPaste,pasteID )
```